# Explanation of the Monero Daemon running arguments

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization, daemon

I started the monero daemon via the GUI on Mac OS X. I downloaded the binary unpacked from `monero-gui-mac-x64-v0.12.0.0.tar.bz2`.

When I do a simple `$ ps aux | grep monero` from the command line I get the following two entries:

```
/private/var/folders/p_/{really long random string}/T/AppTranslocation/{long random hex string}/d/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/MacOS/monerod --detach --data-dir /Users/{username}/Monero/blockchain --check-updates disabled

/private/var/folders/p_/{really long random string}/T/AppTranslocation/{long random hex string}/d/monero-wallet-gui.app/Contents/MacOS/monero-wallet-gui -psn_0_3179605
```

I was confused about this so I ran `$ tail -f ~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.log` and I found

```
WARN    daemon  src/daemon/executor.cpp:62  Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.1.0-release) Daemonised
```

This seems off since I downloaded version `v0.12.0.0`.

Some questions:

1. Why the weird `/private/var/folders/p_/` locations?
2. If I want to run the monero daemon, should I run it from this weird folder location, or is there a better way?
3. Should the daemon be on the same version as the GUI (`v0.12.0.0`) or is this an error?

Comment: The command line says the data directory is /Users/{username}/Monero/blockchain, and you say you check for the log in ~/.bitmonero. You're looking at an old log then. The log includes timestamps, double check those.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had a previous version already running. I would close your GUI, `killall monerod`, ensure there are none running with `ps aux | grep monero`, restart the GUI (which starts a daemon automatically).